# decimal numbers in EXT.JS

Tags: extjs

i want the number field to take 8 digits after the point instead it is taking only 4 and rounding the last digit:
i tried using decimalPercision:8, it is doing the same and adding zeros,

```
 {
        name: "latitude",
        fieldLabel: "<spring:message code='input.latitude' text='Latitude' />",
        xtype: "numberfield",
        decimalPercision:8,
        value:0
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toFixed()` function of javascript. `toFixed` convert numbers to string and keep specified number of decimals, like `value.toFixed(8)`